# Can Master Yi's Ultimate quickly destroy Thresh's 'The Box'?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that Highlander makes Master Yi immune to slows. Does this mean that he can withstand the 99% movement speed reduction to destroy the Thresh's The Box in less then a second?

> ACTIVE: After a 0.75 second delay, Thresh summons 5 spectral walls
>   around him that last up to 5 seconds. Enemy champions that touch a
>   wall take magic damage and are slowed by 99% for 2 seconds, but break
>   the wall. Once one wall is broken, the remaining walls deal half
>   damage and apply half the slow duration. An enemy can be affected by
>   multiple walls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're Talking about a real game the answer for a 1 second removal of the cage by a single champion is **NO**. The Builds + Champions required are useless and damage of the ultimate is too high to pull this off

However if you are in a custom game and you have unlimited resources of movementspeed buffs/items then the answer is yes. Because of Yis immunity to slows he can just run through with let's say Zilean Speed up, Boots of swiftness, 4 Zephyr + 1 Mercurial scimitar. You can also pull this off in one second with Olaf by the way but this would require even more movementspeed buffs.

If you don't want to clear it in 1 second but still only with one person I can think of 2 Other champions apart from Yi that can do this without any help.

Leblanc:
Position yourself on an edge wherever one wall will appear. Walk right into the next wall (the edge where you positioned yourself in) and jump to the opposing wall. From there jump right into the corner of the remaining walls and voila, his ult is no more.

Shaco:
Start the same as Leblanc (corner) But with your clone on the opposite site. Move yourself into the wall and your clone and after 2 walls are gone Jump to the last wall. (This could even work within 1 second but it's complicated)

Answer (score 4):

Thresh box does deal damage. Since Yi is immune to the slow, nothing prevents him to hit all the five walls as quickly as possible. However, he will still suffer the damage which sum up to 250 + 125x4 = 750 / 400 + 200x4 = 1200 / 550 + 4x275 = 1650 without counting Thresh's AP.

Answer (score 2):

He will not suffer the movement speed reduction while immune to slow. However, he will still take the damage from the wall. So whether or not he can 'withstand' it is a matter of how much health he has when he runs through them. Regardless even if he dies the wall will be removed and he wouldn't have been slowed.